# Laravel Horizon queue processing, but not receiving expected result

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-horizon

I'm using Laravel Horizon (Redis) and I can't seem to get my jobs to process correctly.

I can see when I make my call to my route I'm receiving:

```
[2019-01-24 12:03:47][7] Processing: App\Jobs\CheckInVisitor
[2019-01-24 12:03:47][7] Processed:  App\Jobs\CheckInVisitor
```

In the log and it looks fine on the Horizon Dashboard.

However my job doesn't appear to run the code.

---

**CheckInVisitor.php**

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Visitor;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class CheckInVisitor implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable;

    protected $visitor;

    public function __construct($visitor)
    {
        $this->visitor = $visitor;
    }

    public function handle()
    {

        Log::info('Creating Visitor');

        $visitor = Visitor::create([
            'forename' => $this->visitor['forename'],
            'surname' => $this->visitor['surname'],
            'email' => $this->visitor['email'],
        ]);

        Log::info('Visitor Created');
        Log::info($visitor);
    }
}
```

The `laravel.log` does not appear to update with my Log statements and my database remains empty from `Model::create` function, I've tried creating an instance first with `$visitor = new Visitor();` then `$visitor->fill()` to no avail.

The horizon dashboard is showing the the job completed successfully. No errors in the log file.

**VisitorController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $array = $request->all();

    CheckInVisitor::dispatch($array['visitor']);

    return response()->json([
        'messsage' => 'received'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Seems like it should work. Do you have the same issue if your queue is `Sync`?

Comment: Just  tested, yeah still not hitting the `Log::info()` function. I've tried running `php artisan queue:work` and again, no avail.  No failed jobs in the DB either.

Comment: Could you possibly edit your answer to add the code where you are doing the dispatch?

Comment: Also, can you add a `failed()` method and `dd($exception)` in it. See [Dealing with failed jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs). Keep it in Sync mode for instant feedback until we are able to see why it's going wrong.

Comment: @Mozammil added dispatch. It's definitely running, at the top of the file I've added in the `use` statement correctly.

Comment: Doesn't seem the job is failing, not throwing the exception, not hitting the `dd($exception)`. I'm running `tail -f laravel.log` and no updates.

Comment: Does it have the same behavior if you don't queue it? i.e. if you remove the `ShouldQueue` interface and the `Queueable` trait?

Comment: Exactly the same, I chucked in the a `Log` underneath the dispatch function for good measure and I received that log just fine. Just seems this job is not playing ball.

Comment: Interesting. No idea at all.. Maybe you could try to dispatch it with this command instead? Not sure if it will change anything: `dispatch_now(new App\Jobs\CheckInVisitor($array['visitor']));`

Comment: Same thing, this is so frustrating!

Comment: Well, last thing: your application is not in maintenance mode, is it?

Comment: I wish it was that simple, unfortunately no It's not in maintenance mode. I have hit a wall. Just gonna keep trying different things. Different jobs etc.

Comment: try this: `$this->dispatch(new CheckInVisitor($array['visitor']));`

Comment: @Mozammil I restarted my computer, problem resolved itself. Not quite sure what was wrong. I appreciate you taking the time to share your thoughts.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got it sorted..

Answer (score 0):

have you defined the fillable in your entity Visitor? most of the time it only happens if you don't defined the entity fillable.

Comment: Yes, I've defined `protected $fillable = ['list', 'of', 'fields'];` Not only that, I'm not hitting the `Log` statements too.

Comment: but you've not defined 'forename', 'surname' and 'email' in fillable array. kindly add these fields in fillable and try again.

Comment: Yes, I have. It's a long list that will not fit in a comment, so I've only displayed the minimal. The 'list', 'of', 'fields' was an example.

Comment: okay, the only way now is to debug it line by line, first of all you've to check if it's coming in Visitor entity by declaring a constructor in entity class and dd there.

Comment: I'm not hitting the first line in the `handle()` function which contains a `Log` statement which **IS NOT** outputting to the log file.

Comment: could you please comment the log statement and try again just to check either your create working or not.